# Message encryption between two users

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, pycrypto

I'm writing a python script just to practice cryptography. I want to create a small program with Users who can send themselves messages, that have to be encrypted and decrypted. I created 3 classes. The first one contains the 2 functions with which I can `encrypt` and `decrypt` a message using a public and private key. The second class is the `Message` class, which has 4 attributes(the `sender`, the `text` of the message, the `recipient` and a `timestamp`). With the class method `__str__`, I create the actual message which has to be sent in this format: `From {the name of the sender}: {Message} {timestamp}`. The third class is `User`. With `User`, I can initialize each user with a `name`, `public` and `private` key, an inbox to receive encrypted messages and a list called messages to store each message received and decrypted. Each user can send a message to another user, by encrypting the message with the recipient's public key, who can then decrypt the encrypted message with his own private key. I want to do this by using the 2 functions `send`, which encrypts the message and sends it into the recipient inbox. This function has to be used by the sender and the `send` function runs the `receive` function of the recipient, which iterates over new messages, `decrypts` and `appends` the message (`From {sender.name} ...`) to the messages list.

Then I tried to run the program by creating 2 users (Bob and Alice) and send some messages. But I get some errors.

I tried to use the `encrypt` and `decrypt` functions just for encrypting and decrypting a simple string (without users and other stuff I added) and are actually working.

I found the two functions here(encrypt and decrypt) : https://medium.com/@securegns/implementing-asymmetric-encryption-to-secure-your-project-35368049cb5f

I'm an absolute beginner with cryptography, I might have used bad practice.

What could the problem be? I can't figure it out

```
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
import base64
import datetime

class Crypt:

    @staticmethod
    def encrypt(public_key, text):
        cipher_text = public_key.encrypt(text, 32)[0]
        b64cipher = base64.b64encode(cipher_text)
        return b64cipher
    
    @staticmethod
    def decrypt(private_key, b64cipher):
        decoded_ciphertext = base64.b64decode(b64cipher)
        plain_text = private_key.decrypt(decoded_ciphertext)
        return plain_text

class Message:
    def __init__(self, sender, txt, recipient):
        self.sender = sender
        self.txt = txt
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().date()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"From {self.sender}: {self.txt} {self.timestamp}"


class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        random = Random.new().read
        self.name = name
        self.private_key = RSA.generate(1024, random)
        self.public_key = self.private_key.publickey()
        self.inbox = []
        self.messages = []

    def receive(self):
        # Decrypts encrypted messages in the inbox and transfers the decrypted messages into the messages 
          list
        for i in self.inbox:
            message = Crypt.decrypt(self.private_key, i)
            self.messages.append(message)
            self.inbox.pop()
        return self.messages

    def send(self, msg, recipient): 
        # User use send function and encrypts the message with the recipient's public key and appends into the recipient's inbox the encrypted message
        message = Message(self.name, msg, recipient)
        b64cipher = Crypt.encrypt(recipient.public_key, message.__str__())
        self.messages.append(message.__str__())
        recipient.inbox.append(b64cipher)
        recipient.receive()

Bob = User("Bob")

Alice = User("Alice")

Bob.send("Hi", Alice)
Alice.send("Hi Bob!", Bob)
Bob.send("How are you?", Alice)
```

**ERRORS**

```
File "\encrypt.py", line 59, in send
    b64cipher = Crypt.encrypt(recipient.public_key, message.__str__())

File \encrypt.py", line 11, in encrypt
    cipher_text = public_key.encrypt(text, 32)[0]


File "Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 150, in encrypt
    return pubkey.pubkey.encrypt(self, plaintext, K)

File "\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py", line 75, in encrypt
    ciphertext=self._encrypt(plaintext, K)

File "\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 224, in _encrypt
    return (self.key._encrypt(c),)

File "\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py", line 65, in _encrypt
    return pow(m, self.e, self.n)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for pow(): 'str', 'int', 'int'
```

**SOLUTION**

```
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from  Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto import Random
import base64
import datetime


class Crypt:

    @staticmethod
    def encrypt(public_key, text):
        oaep = PKCS1_OAEP.new(public_key, SHA256)
        ciphertext = oaep.encrypt(bytes(text, encoding="ASCII"))
        # cipher_text = public_key.encrypt(text, 32)[0]
        b64cipher = base64.b64encode(ciphertext)
        return b64cipher

    @staticmethod
    def decrypt(private_key, b64cipher):
        decoded_ciphertext = base64.b64decode(b64cipher)
        oaep = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key, SHA256)
        plaintext = oaep.decrypt(decoded_ciphertext)

        # plain_text = private_key.decrypt(decoded_ciphertext)
        print("Decrypted Plaintext: {}".format(plaintext))
        return plaintext


class Message:
    def __init__(self, sender, txt, recipient):
        self.sender = sender
        self.txt = txt
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().date()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"From {self.sender}: {self.txt} {self.timestamp}"


class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        random = Random.new().read
        self.name = name
        self.private_key = RSA.generate(1024, random)
        self.public_key = self.private_key.publickey()
        self.inbox = []
        self.messages = []

    def receive(self):
        # Decrypts encrypted messages in the inbox and transfers the decrypted messages into the messages
        list
        for i in self.inbox:
            message = Crypt.decrypt(self.private_key, i)
            self.messages.append(message)
            self.inbox.pop()
            return self.messages

    def send(self, msg, recipient):
        # User use send function and encrypts the message with the recipient's public key and appends into the recipient's inbox the encrypted message
        message = Message(self.name, msg, recipient)
        b64cipher = Crypt.encrypt(recipient.public_key, message.__str__())
        self.messages.append(message.__str__())
        recipient.inbox.append(b64cipher)
        recipient.receive()


Bob = User("Bob")
Alice = User("Alice")
Bob.send("Hi", Alice)
Alice.send("Hi Bob!", Bob)
Bob.send("How are you?", Alice)
```

Comment: Your `message` class should have a sequence number as well so the recipient can tell if a message is out of order or repeated.

Comment: Did the answer work for you as expected?

Comment: Yes the answer works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Is Your Code after fixing it

```
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from  Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto import Random
import base64
import datetime


class Crypt:

    @staticmethod
    def encrypt(public_key, text):
        oaep = PKCS1_OAEP.new(public_key, SHA256)
        ciphertext = oaep.encrypt(bytes(text, encoding="ASCII"))
        # cipher_text = public_key.encrypt(text, 32)[0]
        b64cipher = base64.b64encode(ciphertext)
        return b64cipher

    @staticmethod
    def decrypt(private_key, b64cipher):
        decoded_ciphertext = base64.b64decode(b64cipher)
        oaep = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key, SHA256)
        plaintext = oaep.decrypt(decoded_ciphertext)

        # plain_text = private_key.decrypt(decoded_ciphertext)
        print("Decrypted Plaintext: {}".format(plaintext))
        return plaintext


class Message:
    def __init__(self, sender, txt, recipient):
        self.sender = sender
        self.txt = txt
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().date()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"From {self.sender}: {self.txt} {self.timestamp}"


class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        random = Random.new().read
        self.name = name
        self.private_key = RSA.generate(1024, random)
        self.public_key = self.private_key.publickey()
        self.inbox = []
        self.messages = []

    def receive(self):
        # Decrypts encrypted messages in the inbox and transfers the decrypted messages into the messages
        list
        for i in self.inbox:
            message = Crypt.decrypt(self.private_key, i)
            self.messages.append(message)
            self.inbox.pop()
            return self.messages

    def send(self, msg, recipient):
        # User use send function and encrypts the message with the recipient's public key and appends into the recipient's inbox the encrypted message
        message = Message(self.name, msg, recipient)
        b64cipher = Crypt.encrypt(recipient.public_key, message.__str__())
        self.messages.append(message.__str__())
        recipient.inbox.append(b64cipher)
        recipient.receive()


Bob = User("Bob")
Alice = User("Alice")
Bob.send("Hi", Alice)
Alice.send("Hi Bob!", Bob)
Bob.send("How are you?", Alice)
```

It print the correct plaintext. I used `OAEP` for encryption and decryption, since It is not advisable to encrypt plaintext alone in `RSA` since RSA is malleable so so must use an encryption that add some randomness to the plaintext see this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using https://github.com/pycrypto/pycrypto and your python version is >3.5?
It says that PyCrypto is written and tested using Python version 2.1 through 3.3.

Please update to https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome and then see if it works.
The second lib takes care of converting to Integar before calling pow().

The first one also has checks in [this file](https://github.com/pycrypto/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/PublicKey/pubkey.py) but they seem to be using  types.StringType which is no longer present after python 2.7. They use 2to3 during setup to make it work with python3 but types.StringType converts to bytes which fails on latest python.

```
-if isinstance(plaintext, types.StringType):
+if isinstance(plaintext, bytes):
```

Also check [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/5gn3q8/what_crypto_library_should_one_use_in_python/) for other crypto libraries